# Unity Button in world space is not clickable when Collider is in front of button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button in world space and my sphere collider is blocking it when it is in front of the button. It is not a trigger. The collider gets to be turned off at some points in the game.

How do I unblock the raycast when the user wants to press the button when though the collider is on? Is there anyway?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html). Your button should be on UI layer, and your collider should be on layer that is not blocking UI.

Comment: It worked by setting the Camera’s Physics Raycaster to “Nothing” from “Everything” where it was. Why is this?

Comment: This way none of physic objects will collide with raycast. While this will solve your current issue, it will backfire when you will need to select a game object